# target: link in gephi through excel

Tags: excel, gephi

I'm doing some work across two visualisation packages, primarily Gephi but also a bespoke package called Linkoder.

They can both use .CSV formats, but data must be laid out differently, and I'm trying to find a way to do this quickly in Excel.  Transpose, Offset, Direct commands all seem to come close, but not quite.

Based on my transcript, I need to convert this matrix:

```
Statement   |  links

No1         | 5 4 3 2 1

No2         | 3 1

No3         | 6 4 2 

No4         | 5 2 1
```

...to this target-link format:

```
Target    | Link

No1       | 5

No1       | 4

No1       | 3

No1       | 2

No1       | 1

No2       | 3

No2       | 1

No3       | 6
```

I am struggling to find a simple way to do this, but that's likely because I'm less adept at Excel formulations that I would like to be.

Anyone refer me to a command (or set) which can quickly convert between these formats?  Because I'm looking at thousands of lines of links to convert...

Thanks in advance! 
hey_arno

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are ways to do that in Excel they are semi-automatic AFAIK. I would recommend you to have a look at [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/), which is a tool to manipulate and tidy datasets. It can read from many sources including Excel. What you need is to split the `Link` column by space and then *Transpose* the resulting columns.

Check this [tutorial](http://okfnlabs.org/handbook/data/patterns/cleaning-spending-data-open-refine/) and scroll down to **Transposing columns** for instruction on how to do it.